# Authorisation System Database Design

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I am working on an Authorization system for a CMS. I have following table structure:
All the other tables are ok for me but i want to know about the best practice 
for a **GroupPermission** table as described below.

Users:
UserId,Name

Groups:
GroupId,Name

GroupUser:
GroupUserId,GroupId,UserId

Modules:
ModuleId,Name

Permissions:
PermissionId,Name,ModuleId,isAllowed

Approach 1:
**GroupPermission:**

```
GPId   GroupId  ModuleId  Permissions(var char)  
 1       1        1       View:true,Create:false,Delete:true,Edit:false  
 2       1        2       View:ture,inviceCreate:false,AssignCreate:false
```

Approach 2:
**GroupPermission:**

```
GPId  GroupId  PermissionId

 1      1         1

 2      1         2

 3      1         3
```

I need your suggestion over the two approaches mentioned ,in first approach there is an advantage of  only one row returned for a specific Group but i am concatenating Permissions in a string , so there would be an overhead of string parsing method,
In second approach i am using 'Id' instead of string.

since this table is the mostly used table and would effect the overall performance of application , so this table needs to be optimized to the maximum.

I have studied the databases of other Cms like word press,orchard,silver stripe etc but they only have few user and Groups tables and couldn't find anything useful for my requirement.

Any other alternate suggestions or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be nice if some one can tell me the reason for being downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with the second, normalized approach.
Keeping delimited data in a single column is wrong in 99.999% of the cases.
Having only a single row for each group permision is not an advantage, considering the string manipulation overhead for otherwise is le selects, inserts, updates and deletes.

Just take a moment to think what if someone wants to remove a permision from a group: you will have to figure out if the group even have this permoision, and then find out where it's text starts and where it ends, cut it out of the full string, and only then update the record.
While with the normalized version all you have to do is write a simple delete statement...

Comment: First thanks, atleast some responded with some suggetion rather than a downvote without any reason. I also have a view point that i should not use concatenated string but what do you think if the data would return multiple rows instead of one.

Comment: Actually my seniors have built this functionality earlier with approach one so they are forcing me to aply that approach, thats why i am fearing that i may be something missing which may bring a loss later.

Comment: Your seniors are simply wrong. I would advise you to try and explain that the normalized approach is better. If you have to, create a demo database. In they are not convinced, then either go with the flow and use approach no. 1, or find a better job.

Comment: Yes you are right , the first approach is also difficult to implement,needs extra parsing methods and in a long run its an invitation for big headaches,i am going to implement the second one.Thanks

Comment: Btw, if an answer solved your problem you should accept it, so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks man , and  i don't have to leave job :),  i hope i will convince them.